# Configuring Local Apt Repo 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, apt-mirror

I am new to Ubuntu but have been working with RHEL for a few years now. I am trying to set up a local repo for 16.04 and am getting "404 Not Found" errors when I run **apt update** from a local machine. Some background, I know this version isn't supported anymore and I work in a closed environment where the repositories I am mirroring exist. Here is what I have done so far....

```
root@ubuntumirror: cat /etc/apt/mirror.list
set base_path    /apt-mirror
deb-amd64 http://<pathtorepo>/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://<pathtorepo>/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://<pathtorepo>/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://<pathtorepo>/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://<pathtorepo>/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

path to repo's is modified because I don't have enough reputation to post that many links...

`apt-mirror`

```
apt install apache2
ln -s /apt-mirror /var/www/html/ubuntu
systemctl restart apache2
```

Then from the workstation...

```
root@ubuntuworkstation: cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb [trusted=yes] http://ubuntumirror/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb [trusted=yes] http://ubuntumirror/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb [trusted=yes] http://ubuntumirror/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb [trusted=yes] http://ubuntumirror/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb [trusted=yes] http://ubuntumirror/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

`apt update` goes through IGN:101 and has a couple of 404 Not Found errors, then gets to the end,

```
Reading package lists... Done
```

Then has `E: Failed to fetch ... 404 Not Found` listed for each entry from the sources.list. It also shows

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have also tried searching or installing individual packages and they all fail. Any advice?? I feel like I am overlooking something small but haven't had any luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

You have to permit Apache to follow Symlink, read the following existing thread.

https://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks

Comment: I changed the apache configs to allow sym links and received the same errors. Just in case, I did "mount --bind /apt-mirror/Ubuntu /var/www/html/Ubuntu and received the exact same errors as before. I restarted the apache2 service every time I made a change as well.

Comment: Did you put capital letter as well ? this part of URL is case sensitive.

Comment: No, this website seems to be doing that automatically for me

Comment: I can also access it through a browser, if that helps.